# Fixed-Fluid-Fixed Layout for 960.gs

Tags: css, layout, grid, fluid-layout, 960.gs

Our website engine uses 960.gs grid system and I am trying to modify it to 3 columns Fixed(100px)-Fluid(max to width)-Fixed(100px) view. Unfortunately all 960.gs online generators makes just or full-fixed or full-fluid grids. So I am trying modify originally generated full-fluid grid to this view:

```
<------------100%--------------->

======== =============== ========
| fixed| |max to screen| |fixed |
======== =============== ========

<-100px>                 <-100px>
```

The Code (after modification):
http://jsfiddle.net/vZm8x/

- Problem 1) I am not sure how to make central content area max to left
  on the screen. Because width:auto; doesn't work at all, width:100% just wrapping divs.
- Problem 2) after fixed to 100px all div it continues wrapping down
  anything. (display:inline; doesn't help any ideas?)

My question is: Is that possible to modify 960.gs template according to our needs? If yes please give me any advice to fix the problems? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With fixed-width side columns, it's actually very easy. You're going to want to use floats, and may need to do a [faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) trick, depending on your specific design needs.

You'll want something along the lines of:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="middle">Content</div>
```

and:

```
div {
    /* border-box, to make sure "width" is our intended width */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox still uses prefix */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    background: #00f;
}

.middle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tYHB/) (this is without the faux column effect, but should give you a starting point). If you change the width of the section with the output, you'll see that the columns stay put, and the content stays within the bounds of the outer columns.

The content column needs to be last, because it's still in the document flow, so the right column would end up below the content.

Alternatively, you can use `position: absolute;` on your side columns with something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative; /* Constrains the columns within their parent. Not needed if parent is <body> */
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.middle {
  padding: 0 100px;
}

div {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

These tricks will work in IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. IE7 might have issues due to using the W3C box model ("content-box") and not recognizing the `box-sizing` CSS, but [there are a few tricks](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2012/08/01/emulate-box-sizing-in-ie7/) to make it work if you need it. IE6 should be okay, because it uses "border-box" based box model by default. (You may need to play with `z-index` to get IE to behave. If so, then set `.middle{ position: relative; z-index: 1}` and add `z-index: 2` to the left and right columns.)

The `position: absolute` trick does have the advantage over the float one in that your sidebars can appear before or after the content div, making it the potentially more semantic option.

The reason these work is because a) your side columns are fixed, so we just set the padding to the width of those columns, and b) `position: absolute` and `float: [left/right]` take the elements out of the document flow, which means that as far as the document is concerned, they aren't there and take no space. This allows other elements to move to where those elements used to be, layering them over top of each other.